# c# | Tic Tac Toe | Console | Having issues implementing a way to stop position changes

Tags: c#

So a few things, I know the positions could be made into a array & should be a char variable. Also, my bot is just using random numbers for its next position.

My issue is that nothing is stopping the player from choosing a already chosen position, same for the bot.

https://pastebin.com/xnGpBFS6

```
  // asks player 
            Console.Write("Select Position: ");
            pselect = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 
            // Switch finds out and changes spot
 
            Console.Clear(); // Clears Console
 
            switch (pselect)
            {
                case 1:
                    s1 = "X";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    s2 = "X";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    s3 = "X";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    s4 = "X";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    s5 = "X";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    s6 = "X";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    s7 = "X";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    s8 = "X";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    s9 = "X";
                    break;
            }
 
            // Checks for winner
            // Horizontal
            if (s1.Contains("X") && s2.Contains("X") && s3.Contains("X"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player Wins!");
                pwins++; // adds player 1 win
                lcheck = 0; // stops loop
                pwinner = 1;
 
            }
            else if (s4.Contains("X") && s5.Contains("X") && s6.Contains("X"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player Wins!");
                pwins++; // adds player 1 win
                lcheck = 0; // stops loop
                pwinner = 1;
 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to prevent already filled boxes from being selected.

My first instinct would be to refer to the boxes by an index. (Similar to the boxes in sudoku.)

Then it's just a simple matter of having the empty boxes ids in a list and removing them as selections are made.

Then during the selection, you'd check if the selection is free; if so, make the move, else ask for a new one.

I also made Tic-Tac-Toe using C# some months ago.
You could take a look at how I approached this problem. (Though don't just copy mine.) [My Tic-Tac-Toe Github repo](https://github.com/SpaceBeeGaming/TicTacToe)